# How to fix this issue `Realm accessed from incorrect thread.` in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, realm, background-thread, uisearchbardelegate

I tried to debug and trace what line the error occur , and I found out the error occur after reading the `print(tcb_filteredArray)` and I tried to put the `print(tcb_filteredArray)` below the `self.tableView.reloadData()` and make a debug and trace it again and it still error occur in `print(tcb_filteredArray)`

**My search filtering code**

```
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let tcb = realm.objects(TrialCourtBranches.self)
        let tcb_safe = ThreadSafeReference(to: tcb)
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).sync {
            guard let filtered = realm.resolve(tcb_safe) else{ return }
            tcb_filteredArray = filtered.filter({ $0.branch_name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || ($0.loc?.pc?.province.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))! || ($0.loc?.pc?.city_municipality.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))! || $0.office_no.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the correct answer**

```
searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty.debounce(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { (data) in
                let realm = try! Realm()
                let tcb = realm.objects(TrialCourtBranches.self)
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(branch_name CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (office_no CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (loc.pc.city_municipality CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (loc.pc.province CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (loc.address1 CONTAINS[c] %@)",data.lowercased(),data.lowercased(),data.lowercased(),data.lowercased(),data.lowercased())
                tcb_filteredArray = tcb.filter(predicate)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }, onError: { (errorResult) in
                print(errorResult)
            }, onCompleted: {
                print("onCompleted")
            }, onDisposed: {
                print("onDisposed")
            })
        .disposed(by: bag)
```

Answer (score 4):

Realm objects, by default, can only be accessed from the thread on which they are created.  So your array of filtered objects, created on a background thread, cannot be accessed straightforwardly on the main thread.

Realm offers a couple of solutions to this - see [this blog post](https://realm.io/blog/obj-c-swift-2-2-thread-safe-reference-sort-properties-relationships/) for further details.

The post describes a few ways of solving the problem:

1. Create (an) unmanaged Realm object(s) containing the relevant data (the problem occurs only with objects backed by a realm).
2. Read the data out into a variable with a thread safe type (e.g. string, int etc)
3. Use the new `ThreadSafeReference` class - with the following steps:

   - Create a reference in the original thread:
     `let personRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: person)`

     (where `person` is a Realm backed object)
   - Inside the second thread block, resolve the reference:

     ```
      let realm = try! Realm()
      guard let person = realm.resolve(personRef) else {
        return // person was deleted
      }
     ```

You'll need to wrap each of the items in your array in a `ThreadSafeReference` if you go down this route.

Comment: i will try this sir @Rich Tolley

Comment: I edited my code please have a look at top, there's an error @Rich Tolley

Comment: @jpcarts23 Looks like you're passing the original collection into the `ThreadSafeReference`, and not the filtered output, so you have a type mismatch. Not sure what types the `ThreadSafeReference` can wrap - you may need to use a map to wrap each realm object ref individually and then unwrap them on the other side

Comment: edited post again , please have a look , still not match @Rich Tolley

Comment: something like `let tcbSafeArray = tcbFilteredArray.map { ThreadSafeReference(to: $0) }`, then individually unwrap them. Also you have a missing `let` in the main thread block `guard`

Comment: @jpcarts23 You shouldn't need to wrap the array itself - you've already wrapped each object in it. Try passing `tcbSafeArray` into the block and then iterate or `map` over it and unwrap each object individually, i.e. the reverse of what you did in the first `map`

Comment: I don't know what to pass and where to pass the variables